# VirtualBox guest OS reports higher than actual storage usage

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, disk-space

I've been using VirtualBox on Windows 7 to run a guest OS of Ubuntu Server 13.04. Generally this has been used for local testing of MongoDB which claims to be out of space.

The guest OS has been given 8.0GB of space and both VirtualBox and Windows 7 explorer show that the virtual disk is between 3.2GB and 3.4GB in size.

Within the Ubuntu VM, it reports that it is using just over 6GB.

> Usage of /: 86.3% of 7.02GB

I've done a `fcsk` as well just to see if that helped, but nothing changed. Below is an output of `sudo df`

```
Filesystem                            1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vbfspkin--ubuntu--vg-root   7359808 6352296    626996  92% /
none                                          4       0         4   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev                                     241648       4    241644   1% /dev
tmpfs                                     50296    1400     48896   3% /run
none                                       5120       0      5120   0% /run/lock
none                                     251468       0    251468   0% /run/shm
none                                     102400       0    102400   0% /run/user
/dev/sda1                                233191   30115    190635  14% /boot
```

I had a bluescreen in Windows 7 a week or so ago and I'm guessing it's related. Anyone know how to fix this issue with the disk usage?

**Update**

Here are two screenshots showing this.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is the virtual disk compressed, or do you have data deduplication turned on? Both can significantly shrink the size of a virtual disk image relative to the guest view.

Comment: I don't believe so. I've never set anything up like that and not sure how to. Is there any way to check?

Comment: I think it's enabled by default, though I'd have to check when I get home as I don't have Virtual Box installed on my laptop here at work.

Comment: I managed to expand the root partition with VBoxManage and Gparted to 11GB, but it still says 7.02GB. I'm guessing something else is awry so I've given up and rebuilt the VM since it's just stock with MongoDB